# Handling shift+enter for newline, enter to send in TextEditor SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I'm trying to handle shift+enter for newline in a text box (that chat apps e.g. WhatsApp, Discord etc. implement). Currently, I'm using a SwiftUI TextEditor, but that doesn't have any way to handle raw keyboard events like you can do in AppKit. So, a hackish solution is to check if the last character of the message is a newline in .onchange, then send the message. This approach works for "enter to send", but I can't find a way to *not* send the message if the shift key is pressed (for multiline messages).

I was trying out an approach using `NSViewRepresentable` to use AppKit APIs as follows:

```swift
struct KeyEventHandling: NSViewRepresentable {
    class KeyView: NSView {
        override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { true }
        
        override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
            print("keydown event")
        }

        override func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent) {
            switch event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) {
            case [.shift]:
                print("shift key pressed")
            default:
                print("no modifier keys are pressed")
            }
        }
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = KeyView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // wait till next event cycle
            view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) { }
}
```

I then set it as a overlay/background (tried both) of the TextEditor like so:

```swift
TextEditor(text: $message)
    .overlay(KeyEventHandling())
    ...more modifiers
```

However, it only seems to handle the events while the TextEditor isn't focused. When the TextEditor (or any other element, it seems) is focused, pressing shift doesn't call the flagsChanged override.

Is there a better approach, short of reimplementing the whole TextEditor as a `NSViewRepresentable`, to receive modifier key state changes? Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct shortcut for new line is actually option+return and `TextField` supports it, e.g.

```
TextField("type something...", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { _ in     
    print("changed") 
}, onCommit: { 
    print("commit") 
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering this question, its appreciated. Is there any way to recreate TextEditor-like functionality using TextField, specifically multi-line input?

Comment: Hi as I said TextField supports multi line input just press option-return to create a new line

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot and see if it works! If it does I'll mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Although this approach with a TextField appears to support adding newlines, it doesn't wrap text like TextEditor does. Is there any way to add text wrapping support?

Comment: That depends on your layout, you could post another question with your code.

Comment: doesnt help because textfield can't take newlines